# Convert list into functor parameter

Tags: prolog

I got stuck to implement a logic. At some instance in my program I have a list say named as  List.
The length of this List is variable and I don't know in advance. Now I have to pass this list in a functor to create a fact and I am unable to implement it. For eg:

if List is `[first]` then it should add the fact `functor(first).`
if List is `[first,second]` then it should add the fact `functor(first,second).`
if List is `[first,second,third]` then it should add the fact `functor(first,second,third).`
and so on...

I was trying by `=..` but here I am unable to map that variable length constraint. For fixed length I am able to perform but I don't know in advance that how many elements will be there in list.

Any suggestions to implement this logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite understand your problem with `=..` but this worked for me:

```
 assert_list(List) :-
            Term =.. [my_functor|List],
            assert(Term).
```

Note that I use `my_functor` instead of simply `functor` because `functor/3` is a built-in predicate so you cannot assert ternary `functor` facts (`functor(first, second, third)`).

Calling it:

```
 ?- assert_list([first,second,third]).
 true.
```

Checking that it works:

```
 ?- listing(my_functor).
 :- dynamic user:my_functor/3.

 user:my_functor(first, second, third).

 true.
```

Note that technically, the different n-ary `my_functor/n` predicates are not the same predicates. You must use different queries in your program for each n. To circumvent this, you could simply assert the list as one and only argument of `my_functor`:

```
 ?- List = [first, second, third],
 assert(my_functor(List)).
 true.

 ?- listing(my_functor).
 :- dynamic user:my_functor/3.

 user:my_functor([first, second, third]).

 true.
```

My SWI-Prolog version is 5.7.5.